# foreground and background process bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, process

How do I start one process(bg) and execute second process(fg) after that. Now both processes are running in parallel. When second(fg) process is finished, get back to first process(bg). kill it.

Tried this : process bg & (process fg; wait %2; fg %1; kill -9 %1)

Tried many different ways. But doesn't seems to work as expected. Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sleep 5 & sleep 3; kill %1
```

Comment: `kill %+` might be safer than `kill %1`, since there might be other background jobs running, or even that job 1 does not exist (if it was running previously and finished after the `sleep 5` started).

Comment: @cdarke: Thank you for this hint.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have some doubts, 1. I see second process is sleep for 3 seconds and hence it will end before sleep 5.  2. What is my first process runs till I press ^c. 3. In my scenario my first process Which exits only if I press ^c, so I force kill it and second will exit once process execution is done.  Above answer is still killing by first process while second process is in progress.